# OnClickListener() in onCreate()?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Would this be an appropriate way of setting up a button for taking a picture? Not trying to start an activity just trying to get the other methods in the activity to run when the button is clicked. Thanks

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    if(checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext())){
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    }

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    button_capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    button_capture.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get an image from the camera
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem in having `OnClickListener()` in `onCreate()`. In fact, all the `ClickListeners` must be initialized as soon as possible before user gets to interact with your `Activity`. So, `onCreate` is a perfectly right place to do it.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. Is there something else I need to do because my code doesn't seem to be registering the click when it happens. I just put a little system.out.print and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It should work as long as your `layout` file has the specific `id` on which you are setting an `onClickListener`. If you are working on a code snippet that is different than the one you have posted above then it would help if you can share that as well.

Comment: Yeah I have that, it's just that the pictures I take only appear after I've removed the device from usb and don't appear at all when it runs by itself.

Comment: That might be because the `MediaScanner` is not running after you take pictures using your code. You can run `MediaScanner` programmatically too after taking pictures but that's the next roadblock for you. In context to this question, I hope you got your answer. Cheers!

Comment: Wow, see that's the kind of community I like to see. Thank you so much, I would have been completely lost without this perspective; even if if isn't the solution to my problem! But it probably is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind OnClickListener in oncreate so that it responds to user interaction when activity is loaded.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm not quite sure what you mean; isn't that what I've done?

Comment: @masteryupa  ya you have done it, you need to register click listeners on on create so that it responds when activity is loaded on screen or you can  do it from xml too. To conform if your event is triggered or not   instead of system.out.print use log.i/d you can view your result in logcat. `<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="callme" />`